# File Upload because of array it identify always a file there

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm doing at file uploading function, but when i trying to do filter up person who din't upload file.

I notice that Array[] in my html causing always there is a file available there.

Once i try to remove the array[] in my HTML, the PHP file identify works normally... need some help here.

Thank YOU.

HTML:

```
<label class="btn btn-default btn-file button-upload" >
<input type="file" name="file[]" hidden class="input-file-form" multiple="multiple">
</label>
```

PHP:

```
if($_FILES['file']["error"] == 4) {
    echo "no file";
} else {
    echo "got file";
}
```

Comment: need some help here :(

Answer (score 3):

it's an array so you should refer to it as an array. Try `$_FILES['file']["error"][0]`. If that works, you can use `foreach` to iterate all the files:

### [VIEW DEMO](http://deepcorelabs.com/projects/so/fileupload.php)

Here's the code:

```
<pre>
<?php
print_r($_FILES);

foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $file){

  if($_FILES['file']["error"][$key] == 4) {
      echo "no file <br>";
  } else {
      echo "got file <br>";
  }

}

?>
</pre>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label class="btn btn-default btn-file button-upload" >
        <input type="file" name="file[]" class="input-file-form" multiple="multiple">
    </label>        
    <br>

    <label class="btn btn-default btn-file button-upload" >
        <input type="file" name="file[]" class="input-file-form" multiple="multiple">
    </label>    
    <br>

    <button>Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: it shows :
Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebEnt\testingupload.php on line 2
and still telling file was there, although no file

Comment: do `var_dumb($_FILES)` and paste what you get.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebEnt\testingupload.php on line 6

Comment: line 6 was the foreach part

Comment: Just updated the answer with working demo. It should be `$_FILES['file'] as $file`. And `$_FILES['file'][0]` would be your first file etc.

Comment: Actually it's more complex than that. Just added link in the updated answer.

Comment: it so weird... in your demo is working but in my site was showing error, Undefined index: & Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I also changed the code. Examine it carefully and find the differences.